# Disable event/refresh on certain Options on dropdownlist

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, events, html-select

Here is a part of my ASP.NET page.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server"  
            OnChange="return ListChange(this.value)" 
            onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged1" 
            AutoPostBack="True" >
            <asp:ListItem Selected="True">Today</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Yesterday</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="1">Specific Day</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>All Time</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Here is the Javascript.

```
function ListChange(txtVal) {
   if (txtVal != 1 ) {
       document.getElementById("txtDate").setAttribute("style", "visibility:hidden;");
       return true;
   }
   else {
       document.getElementById("txtDate").setAttribute("style", "visibility:visible;");
       return false;
   }
}
```

Here the objective is to show certain data according to the option selected by the user. In the Specific Day option, a textbox is shown to the user to insert date through javascript. But the `onselectedindexchanged` event is also raised which calls to server. I want to stop the event when "specific day" option is selected, but run when other options selected.

The code on `OnChange="return ListChange(this.value)"` is not stopping the event as used to when using a form with button.

Comment: ideally it should work , did you try by changing it to something like  onchange="Javascript:return ListChange(this.value);"

Comment: that stops the event for all options :/

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you do the show & hide using the .net code.

For example in VB.net

Put the following code in the DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged1 sub.

```
   If DropDownList1.SelectedValue = "1" Then
        txtDate.Visible = True
    Else
        txtDate.Visible = False
    End If
```

Rather than have 3 different on click/change events.

Then remove the JS and the on change and on client click events, just leave it with onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged1"

**UPDATE:**

If you want to avoid postback for some events in your code do :

If isPostBack = True

//Don't fill form stuff

Else

//Fill form stuff

End If

Comment: Doing as you say will refresh the page every time a option is selected.

Comment: Well if he wants to attach any code the SelectIndexChange and has AutoPostBack="True" it will always postback. That's how it works.

Comment: thanks for pointing out, but can we disable the postback for certain option selected?

Comment: Sadly not, if you want to make sure the form isn't being filled by other data then do a check isPostBack = True, which will check before running code. Check my update.

Comment: Also have a look at update panel & content templates if you want to avoid the page looking like it's refreshing. update panels and content templates will make it look like nothing has happened, no page flash.

Comment: havent used them till now. Thanks. will be trying your suggestions

Answer (score 0):

It is one of the options that you can use.

1. Remove the selected index change event from markup.
2. on change event , check whether your validation has ran correctly.
3. if they have run make ajax request and do your stuff.

Answer (score 0):

you do not need to call two separate functions simultaneously. Here is some jquery code that will do the trick in just a few lines.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#DropDownList1').change(fnction(){
        if($(this).text() != 'Specific Day') {
          document.getElementById("txtDate").setAttribute("style", "visibility:hidden;");
           return true;
        } else {
          document.getElementById("txtDate").setAttribute("style", "visibility:visible;");
          return false;
        } 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

By default ASP.Net will post back if you give AutoPostBack =true.

It is not considering return values.

Below is the code rendered at execution time. it uses settimeout and executed _doPostBack for submitting Form

```
onchange="return ListChange(this);setTimeout(&#39;__doPostBack(\&#39;ctl00$MainContent$DropDownList1\&#39;,\&#39;\&#39;)&#39;, 0)"
```

We need to think about stopping a form submit by setting a flag like Page_IsValid=false;

Answer (score 0):

First try to check what value is coming in your javascript function.

If its not showing the selceted value use the following code

```
var index = document.getElementById(selectItem).selectedIndex;

    alert("value =" + document.getElementById(selectItem).value);
    alert("text =" + document.getElementById(selectItem).options[index].text);
```

or using jQuery

$("#yourdropdownid option:selected").text();

Comment: I have tested. My javascript works correctly to get the selected value.